# GWT's getResults() of SubmitCompleteEvent returns null after submitting form with FileUpload

Tags: java, file-upload, gwt

After successfully implementing a file upload with `GWT` in one application I tried to transfer this to another application but the string returned from the uploading servlet cannot be retrieved in the provided `SubmitCompleteHandler`. `SubmitCompleteEvent.getResults()` just returns null.

A typical reason for returning null seems to be the uploading servlet is in a different domain. But as the GWT and uploading servlet run in the same context it should not be a cross-domain issue.

The `FileUpload` widget is contained in a `FormPanel`. When clicking a button the form is submitted. This calls a servlet (really, a breakpoint is reached during debugging). In real world it would store the file on server side and return the filename. In this reduced example it just writes a String to the response Writer.

`FormPanel` with `FileUpload` snippet:

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setAction("upload"); // results "upload" directly below context
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
form.setWidget(panel);
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
upload.setName("uploadFormElement");
panel.add(upload);

panel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        form.submit();
    }
}));
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        Window.alert("===> " + event.getResults() + " <==="); // shows "===> null <==="
    }
});
```

`web.xml` snippet:

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

`FileUploadServlet` snippet:

```
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().write("OK");
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }

}
```

Are there any libraries or library versions known to be conflicting with GWT's SubmitCompleteHandler?

Any ideas are appreciated ...

**UPDATE**: After downgrading all artifacts belonging to spring-security from 4.0.4.RELEASE to 3.2.4.RELEASE it works. With upgrading them to 4.1.2.RELEASE it does not work either.

Comment: 1. I don't think that this is GWT issue. Just try to use this servlet on simple plane page with form. Also look at raw response in browser's dev console.
2. May be you have some filter, that wraps HttpServletResponse and Writer. Try to debug by stepping out in callstack frames from breakpoint in servlet, to see last point before response will be sended to caller.

Comment: 1. The servlet works in a different application, response goes back to the browser there. Not so in the other application ... after downgrading all artifacts belonging to spring-security from 4.0.4.RELEASE to 3.2.4.RELEASE it works. With upgrading them to 4.1.2.RELEASE it does not work either. 2. While debugging I saw all filters do still carry the response given from the servlet. But it's no longer in the raw response in the browser.

Comment: May be it is X-Frame-Options header issue. spring-security 4.x appends this header for responses by default. Try to disable this header for checking.

Comment: @AlexanderLeshkin Adding `<s:headers><s:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" /></s:headers>` to `<s:http>` in my `applicationContext.xml`made it work. Thank you very much. Do you want to add an answer that I accept or do you want me to do so?

Comment: I've added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue are related to `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header, that spring-security 4.x appends to responses [1]. Since GWT application typically loaded in iframe, this header makes not possible to properly handle form submission from client code executed in frame.

To fix issue frame options policy should be disabled or switched to `SAMEORIGIN`.
E.g. for xml config into `<s:http>`:

```
<s:headers>
  <s:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
</s:headers>
```

Or for Java config by using `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer.frameOptions()`:

```
 HttpSecurity cfg = ...;
 cfg.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

[1] https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-frame-options

Comment: It's not because of client code being executed in an iframe, it's because the form is submitted to an iframe, so the result page is "displayed" in an iframe (which the header forbids)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change x frame options you can add `X-Frame-Options` as `SAMEORIGIN` in response header. 
Like `response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options","SAMEORIGIN");`